# How to run two routes parallel at start in Apache Camel on Spring?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

Here i have two routes configured to run when i start Apache ServiceMix as daemons. But when i start servicemix what i noticed was each of these routes executed sequentially. I just want to know how to run them at the same time of servicemix start.

```
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="timer://myTimer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=8000" />
        <to uri="bean://passengerUpdateDaemon?method=process"/>
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="timer://myTimer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=8000" />
        <to uri="bean://baggageUpdateDaemon?method=process"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Please tell me how to write this camelcode to run parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unique name of the timer name, eg myTimer and myTimer2